# Can't access files when running program via SSH

Tags: c, bash, ssh, fopen

Here is part of my C program:

```
FILE* f;
f = fopen("data/file.bin","rb");
```

when program is running via SSH like this:
`ssh -t root@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx /tmp/myprog`

fopen() always returns null pointer.

However, when I'm connecting to the device via SSH and running myprog, like this:

```
ssh root@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
cd /tmp/
./myprog
```

fopen() works perfectly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`data/file.bin` is a relative path, so the location it refers to depends on what directory you're in (your "working directory") when you run the program.

If you `cd` to `/tmp` first, it'll resolve to `/tmp/data/file.bin`. If you don't, logging into root probably puts you someplace like `/root`, so it'll resolve to `/root/data/file.bin` instead, and that presumably doesn't exist.

(Note: a program can change its own directory with something like [`chdir()`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/chdir). But by default it just inherits the working directory of whatever ran it, which in this case is going to the shell that `sshd` launched.)